# Beautifulsoup for loops through lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a browser from which I need to scrape data.

On that page, I have multiple lists and in those lists I need to select each element by turn and then get on the next page so this is basically multiple iteration of lists.

To start with, I tried to iterate through the first list.

My code is as follows:

```
 soup1=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')

 for link in soup1.find_all(class_="combo").find_all('option'):

     link.click()
```

It shows up as an error because it says that result set has no attribute as find_all

Answer (score 1):

You have two `find_all()`s in a row, which is probably the issue. Try something like:

```
for link in soup1.find_all(class_="combo"):
   for opt in link.find_all('option'):
          opt.[whatever]
```

Comment: opt.click? Will that be okay?

Comment: it doesn't allow me click on it

Comment: @1010101010 - There's no `click()` method in beautifulsoup; do you mean selenium?

Comment: because I have such multiple for loops for each list.

Comment: @1010101010 - It has nothing to do with multiple loops and lists. It's the fact that there is no `click()` method here. So you have to find something to replace it, or switch to another library that allows it.

Comment: Okay, any suggestions for an alterative?

Comment: @1010101010 - take a look at this, for example: https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html